# How to use strcpy() with array elements?

Tags: c, arrays, string, c-strings

I have an array called `array`, and I want to copy a word that I have read in from some file and store it into that array at a certain index, how can I don it?

I thought when a file is read all input from the file is in "string" form. So if a number 100 is in the file its represented as "100".

I have tried the following:

```
#define maxlength 10

char array[10];
int i = 0;
char word[maxlength];

strcpy(array[i], word); //error
array[i] = word; //error
```

My guess is because the `word` is an array of characters it's not actually a string to copy through. Is there a way I can copy the `word[]` into the `array[]` in a string format? I.E. index 0 in array = ["hello"] index 1 = ["world"] etc.

Comment: Post true code - a [MCVE].  What is `maxlength`?

Comment: *"Is there a way I can copy the word[] into the array[] in a string format. i.e index 0 in array = ["hello"] index 1 = ["world"] etc."* no. You've got an array of characters. The question is: how do you intend to pack `hello` in one character?

Comment: Have you tried `strcpy(array, word);` ?

Comment: `char array[10]` declares an array of `10-char`. When referencing an element of an array `[ ]` acts as a dereference. So while `array` may be type `char *` (due to [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)), `array[i]` is type `char` resulting in your attempt to `strcpy` failing due to `array[i]` being an incompatible type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding of the concept of a "string" might be wrong.

A string in C is nothing else than an array of characters, with the NUL terminator (character `'\0'`) at the end.

What you have here:

```
char array[10];
```

Is not an array of strings, it's just an array of characters. If you want to store an entire string inside `array[0]`, then you'll have to declare your array as an *array of arrays of `char`*, like this:

```
char array[10][10];
```

Now, each element of your `array` can hold a string up to 9 characters long (remember, the last one has to be the terminator `'\0'`).

To copy your `word`, you first have to **be sure that it is a valid string** (it should, again, end with a `'\0'`), and **make sure it's less than 9 characters long** (10 if counting the terminator), because you declared `array[10][10]`. Once you know that it's a correctly formed string, you can copy it:

```
strcpy(array[0], word);
```

If you don't know if `word` is correctly NUL-terminated, or you don't know if it's too long, then you can fisrt try to copy all the 10 characters with `strncpy()`, and then ensure it is terminated correctly putting a `'\0'` at the end manually:

```
strncpy(array[0], word, 10);
array[9] = '\0';
```

Comment: Well, I **did** read the question - it was a bit vague, to be honest, and my answer was an attempt, at least! Still as it seems unpopular, I'll wipe it. But, some of your answer simply repeats what I already said. Hmmm.

Answer (score -1):

First let's clear some syntax errors then we can copy.

1. cahr word[maxlength]; ---> char word[maxlength];
   I hope you have defined maxlength = 10 somewhere because both length should be the same otherwise it will get run time exception.
2. strcpy(array[i], word); //error ---> strcpy(array, word);
   strcpy expects destination and source both should be char* type and you are passing array[i] which is only char type as you access element of array by "[i]" So only use "array" in strcpy.
3. array[i] = word //error ---> don't need this in array copy and even syntactically it is wrong you are trying assigning char* to char.

So our final code snippet would be like this:

```
char array[10];

char word[10] = {'T','h','a','n','k',' ','y','o','u'};

strcpy(array, word); // word is copied to the array

cout << array; ---> Thank you
```

Comment: Your answer will crash (probably) as `word` is not null-terminated!

Comment: @Adrian as it happens there are 9 initializers for an array of size 10, and the rules are that any elements without initializer in this situation get set to `0` .  However it's hard to understand why someone would write this instead of just using a string lteral